# Why is JavaScript function not opening hamburger menu?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time writing a JS function. I am trying to get the navigation bar to open when the hamburger is clicked but it's not working. I have attached my HTML and JS.
It works when I don't allow the function to have any parameter and instead manually write "nav" where nav_type is, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

The code:

```js
/* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon */
function myFunction(nav_type) {
  var i;
  var x;
  for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    x = document.getElementById(nav_type + i);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="Main Navigation" class="topnav">
  <a aria-hidden="true" href="javascript:void(0);" ; class="menu show-mobile" onclick="myFunction(" nav ")">
    <img src="img/menu-icon.svg" alt="toggle menu" />
  </a>

  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="show-mobile">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="humans/humans.html" id="nav1">Humans</a></li>
    <li><a href="other/other.html" id="nav2">Plants, Animals, the Universe, and Other
        </a></li>
    <li class="dropdown" id="nav3">
      <button class="dropbtn" id="nav4" onclick="myFunction(" drp ")">More
          <img src="img/down-arrow.svg" alt="dropdown arrow" class="dropdown-icon icon"/>
        </button>
      <ul class="topnav dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="presentations.html" id="drp1">Presentations</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-islam.html" id="drp2">About Islam</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html" id="drp3" class="active">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet", and click the button, the error will become more apparent. You have mismatched quotes in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are using multiple quotations marks together, the parser is considering the first pair of quotation mark to me the value of the `onload` attribute, which is `"myFunction("` and the rest are considered gibberish.

Use double quotations (") and single quotations (') together to avoid this error

`onclick="myFunction('nav')">`

Similarly

`onclick="myFunction(" drp ")"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `HTMLElement.classList.toggle(class)`

```js
document.querySelector('#navShow').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('ul.topnav').classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
ul.topnav {
  display: none;
}

ul.topnav.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <nav aria-label="Main Navigation" class="topnav">
    <a id="navShow" aria-hidden="true" href="#"; class="menu show-mobile">
        Menu
    </a>
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="show-mobile">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="humans/humans.html" id="nav1">Humans</a></li>
      <li><a href="other/other.html" id="nav2">Plants, Animals, the Universe, and Other
        </a></li>
      <li class="dropdown" id="nav3">
        <button class="dropbtn" id="nav4" onclick="myFunction("drp")">More
          <img src="img/down-arrow.svg" alt="dropdown arrow" class="dropdown-icon icon"/>
        </button>
        <ul class="topnav dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="presentations.html" id="drp1">Presentations</a></li>
          <li><a href="about-islam.html" id="drp2">About Islam</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html" id="drp3" class="active">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

For a more modern approach dispose of Javascript for the function altogether.
Here we use a label and a hidden checkbox combined with CSS to control our menu show/hide.

```css
#chkNav {
  display: none;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

ul.topnav {
  display: none;
}

#chkNav:checked + ul.topnav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="Main Navigation" class="topnav">
    <label for="chkNav" aria-label="show nav">
      <span class="nav-bar"></span>
      <span class="nav-bar"></span>
      <span class="nav-bar"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkNav" />
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="show-mobile">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="humans/humans.html" id="nav1">Humans</a></li>
      <li><a href="other/other.html" id="nav2">Plants, Animals, the Universe, and Other
        </a></li>
      <li class="dropdown" id="nav3">
        <button class="dropbtn" id="nav4" onclick="myFunction("drp")">More
          <img src="img/down-arrow.svg" alt="dropdown arrow" class="dropdown-icon icon"/>
        </button>
        <ul class="topnav dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="presentations.html" id="drp1">Presentations</a></li>
          <li><a href="about-islam.html" id="drp2">About Islam</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html" id="drp3" class="active">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```